# How can I combine multiple Excel worksheets into a single workbook using Perl?

Tags: perl, excel

I am producing 5 different Excel worksheets (.csv file) using Perl. I want to combine all these as one file (Excel workbook) with 5 different worksheets rather then have 5 seperate files.

Don't know if this is possible? IF anyone have any idea on how to do this that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I merge two Excel (xls) files in Perl or batch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789421/how-can-i-merge-two-excel-xls-files-in-perl-or-batch)

Answer (score 7):

You should use the CPAN Module [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel).

It can write different worksheets. At the end there is an example that takes a `tab.txt` file, and write it to a spreadsheet. If you modify this example to take your five files, and each time create a new worksheet in your spreadsheet, your problem is solved.