# Perl - Changing Excel Worksheet name

Tags: excel, perl

In a perl script I am writing, I am trying to find a way to open an existing excel spreadsheet, change the name of the first worksheet, and save it. It would seem like a simple task but I haven't found a simple way to do it.

Spreadsheet::WriteExcel can easily change worksheet name, but it seems like it can't read in an existing excel file.

Another constraint is that the perl module I use shouldn't need installation. I can work around this if there's no good option, but it would make things more complicated.

Edit: I am using ActivePerl 5.18, so modules included in this are ideal.

Comment: Re. "Another constraint is that the perl module I use shouldn't need installation." There are no core modules for manipulating Excel spreadsheets, so you'll have to install one unless you're using ActivePerl, for example. Can you please expand on why you don't want to install modules? You don't need admin rights to install them, if that's your reason.

Comment: Sorry, should have added that detail. I am using ActivePerl 5.18. With the systems I usually work with I've had issues in the past with installing additional modules, so I try to avoid that. If there's no other way, I can install other modules.

Comment: Look at `get_name()` function of [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Worksheet](https://metacpan.org/source/JMCNAMARA/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.59/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel/Worksheet.pm). You can get some idea from here.

Answer (score 1):

The only way of doing this while preserving everything else in the Excel file is to use [Win32::OLE](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::OLE).

That requires having Excel installed on the computer on which the program will be run, and, of course, only works on Windows.

If you can't do that, you will have to read the Excel file, and write out the contents to another file, changing the name of the worksheet in the process. Depending on exactly what you have in the source Excel file, this can get rather involved rather fast.

See also "[How can I merge two Excel (xls) files in Perl or batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6791613/100754)" and "[In Perl, how can I copy a subset of columns from an XLSX work sheet to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29880018/100754)"